# Flask & SQL ALchemy, the created Database has an unknown Type

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I am currently writing a program in python using flask and flask_sqlalchemy. I have done the same steps as in the documentation. But when the database gets created automatically, it has an unknown file type, altough it should be a sqlite database. I am using Pycharm btw.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

# create the extension
db = SQLAlchemy()
# create the app
app = Flask(__name__)
# configure the SQLite database, relative to the app instance folder
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///filemanager.db"
# initialize the app with the extension
db.init_app(app)


class File(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    path = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    type = db.Column(db.String, unique=False, nullable=False)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_database = True
    if create_database:
        with app.app_context():
            db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True, port=5008)
```

I tried to change the file type manually to sqlite, but it still doesn't contain tables and columns. If I create the columns manually in the console everything works, but I have and want to do it programmatically.
I also tried another stackoverflow answer, where he split the code into two files, didn't work eiter.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cannot reproduce, running the above creates a db file with type `instance/filemanager.db: SQLite 3.x database, last written using SQLite version 3032003`.

Comment: @ljmc And the DB contains a column named "file"?

Comment: It contains a table named `file` (using `sqlite> .tables`).

Comment: "it has an unknown file type" Where do you see this?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice in pycharm database files have a database icon. but in this case, it has a questionmark, and when I hover over it, it says: unknown file type". But as I mentioned, using any other names that are not "file" or "filemanger" work for me. Literally every other name. I tried "mydb.db", "fasijfi.db", "datasets.db", they all work. Must be some weird issue maybe a collision with some predefined variables

Comment: It looks like you named your db `filemanager.db`, right. When you say "file" or "filemanager" do you mean you also tried `file.db` as the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the name of the Database and the name of the table. I had "filemanager.db" and "files", these names don't work (don't ask me why), but I tried with "users.db" and "users" and it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "...and the name of the table" I don't think the name of the table should matter here. When you are inspecting the files, PyCharm can't see the table name.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice as I said, all of this makes no sense, but it was still the solution to my problem,

Comment: Since I wasn't clear, let me restate. Are you sure that the problem was both the database and table name? Did you try changing the table name and keeping the table named `files`?